# Does a CSS "#id element" select grandchildren as well?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Say I have a `<div id="container">` with various elements inside of it including tables. Does the CSS selector `#container table` select all tables within the div (including grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc)? Or does it select children only?

Also, if I want to select the first child div within the container div, how would I do that?

Comment: You should [review the spec on selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes; to put it simply, that selects all `table` elements within `#container`, regardless of nesting level.

The space is called the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators). As exactly what it says on the tin, it selects any descendants. That includes children, grandchildren, etc, again regardless of nesting level. It does not only select children; that purpose is served by the [child combinator `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators).<sup>1</sup>

To select the first child within your container as a `div`, you use

```
#container > div:first-child
```

Or if you have something else as the first child and you want to pick the first child that is of type `div`, you use

```
#container > div:first-of-type
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For this purpose, it's often said to select only "direct children", and where people say "children" they often mean "descendants" instead. Strictly speaking, though, "children" refers to immediate nesting level. There's no such thing as an "indirect child".</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```
#container table
```

selects all the descendants which are table.

```
#container > table
```

selects all the children which are table.

Answer (score 3):

`#container table` will select all the `table` elements that are inside of the `#container` element, no matter how deep in the DOM tree they are.
If you want to target only the first level elements, you'd go about using this: `#container > table`

To select the first child div within the container element, you'd do the following: `#container > div:first-child` - this will select only the first level child div. Or, if you want to target all first div elements within the container, you'd use `#container div:first-child`

This is valid only if the `div` is actually the first child of that element

```
<div id="container">
    <div>some content</div>
</div>
```

so, for example there must not be any `p` tag before it (or any other).

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div>some content</div>
</div>
```

If the `div` is not the first child, you'd need to do the following: `#container div:first-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

> Also, if I want to select the first child div within the container
>   div, how would I do that?

```
#container > div{}
```